# Open a gallery image with webview

Tags: android, image, webview

I am making my first app, and there I have photos I want the user could make them bigger with a "zoom effect".
I have been searching about it in the web and I have found I must use a webview which can do that automatically.
But the image doesn't appear. I only can watch his route as a text:         "**file:///storage/sdcard0/postals/4249.jpg**"
And it doesn't matter if I include **"file://"** or not.
Here it is the code. I hope anyone of you could help me.
"Ivpostal" is the name of my webview. And "adrecafoto" is an string with the route of the image in the galery of the phone:

```
**uriruta=Uri.parse(adrecafoto);             
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriruta,null,null,null,null);  
c.moveToNext();  
String filePath = "";  
String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };                  
int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(column[0]);  
if (c.moveToFirst()) {  
    filePath = c.getString(columnIndex);  
}  
c.close();  
String rutafoto= "file://"+filePath;  
ivpostal.loadData(rutafoto, "text/html","utf-8");**
```